# How to integrate apache solr in spring MVC using maven on tomcat

Tags: hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, solr, spring-data-solr

I am developing a web application using **spring MVC** and I have hosted this using **tomcat**. I have a requirement where I want to integrate **apache-solr** to my search engine.

I tried looking on internet for various tutorials but couldn't find a proper one to explain the steps.

**So my requirements are**

1. How to integrate **apache solr** in **spring MVC** using **maven dependency**(I am using tomcat to host the server)
2. Basic tutorials to add data files with solr
3. How can I integrate it to pick up the data from my database. I am using **hibernate** to map my database tables.

After going through some tutorials I think **spring-data-solr** is suitable for spring MVC.

**P.S. I am new to all the above technologies.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Solr in general, you should [refer to the Solr reference guide for help.](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Apache+Solr+Reference+Guide) It is meant for the upcoming Solr 5.0 release, but most of the guide is still relevant for 4.0 and the other documentation (the old wiki) is of poor quality.

Solr requires a separate installation; it is not just a maven dependency. To install Solr, [follow the install instructions from the guide.](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Installing+Solr)

To contact solr in your java layer, you can use `solr-j`, which you can [add as a maven dependency, as noted here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.solr/solr-solrj), the latest version is `4.10.2`:

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
    <version>4.10.2</version>
</dependency>`

[There's lots of documentation about how to use Solr-J here.](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+SolrJ) `spring-data-solr` may also work for you.

Hibernate has nothing to do with the integration of solr and spring. Solr can load from your DB directly using the [data import handler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler) or you can update documents in solr [via its REST API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Managed+Resources).